# BioBERT Inferencing Using TF_Record file and GRPC

Tags: python, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, bert-language-model

I have been trying to perform inference using bioBERT(https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert)
Model and TF serve to perform QA task.

I have succesfully exported the model: My serving function looks like this:

```
feature_columns = [

  tf.feature_column.numeric_column("unique_ids", shape=(FLAGS.max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int64),
  tf.feature_column.numeric_column("input_ids", shape=(FLAGS.max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int64),
  tf.feature_column.numeric_column("input_mask", shape=(FLAGS.max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int64),
  tf.feature_column.numeric_column("segment_ids", shape=(FLAGS.max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int64)
]
```

serving_input_fn=tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))

estimator._export_to_tpu = False

estimator_path = estimator.export_saved_model(estimator_base_path, serving_input_fn, checkpoint_path)
##############################################

I am also able to generate a TFrecord File and trying to utilize TFrecordIterator to iterate over tht tf records file and call the GRPC generated stub.
#record_path is the path to TF_record filw
Function below....

```
all_results = [ ]

record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(pathToTfRecordFile)

for string_record in record_iterator:    
    model_request.inputs['examples'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(string_record,
          dtype=tf.string,
          shape=[batch_size])
  )

  result_future = stub.Predict.future(model_request, 30.0)


  result = result_future.result().outputs


  all_results.append(process_result(result))
```

The Error I am getting is as follows:

```
_MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:

status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT

details = "Name: <unknown>, Key: unique_ids, Index: 0.  Number of int64 values != expected.  Values size: 1 but output shape: [384]
```

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try shaping the unique_ids like this in the service_inputfn.

tf.feature_column.numeric_column("unique_ids", shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int64),